# Broken dependency for lvm2

Tags: debian, software-installation, apt, lvm

I am on fresh Debian jessie system and trying to install lvm2:

```
# apt-get install lvm2
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
lvm2 : Depends: watershed (>= 2) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages
```

`apt-get update`, `upgrade`, `-f`, `autoremove` etc did not help, most importantly, my version of watershed is 7:

```
# aptitude versions watershed
Package watershed:                        
i   7
```

How can I install lvm2?

Comment: `watershed` shouldn't be a dependency of `lvm2` according to https://packages.debian.org/jessie/lvm2 . Please post the output of `apt-cache policy lvm2` and `cat /etc/apt/sources.list`.

Comment: There's no package called `watershed` in Debian. What distribution are you actually running? What package sources do you use?

Comment: I do run Debian: uname -a
"Linux tornado 3.16.0-4-686-pae #1 SMP Debian 3.16.7-ckt25-1 (2016-03-06) i686 GNU/Linux"  where tornade is the name of machine

Comment: apt-cache policy lvm2
lvm2:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 2.02.98-6ubuntu3
  Version table:
     2.02.98-6ubuntu3 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-proposed/main i386 Packages
     2.02.98-6ubuntu2 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main i386 Packages

Comment: cat /etc/apt/sources.list

deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted universe multiverse 
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security main restricted universe multiverse 
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main restricted universe multiverse 
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-proposed main restricted universe multiverse 
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports main restricted universe multiverse